# How to move Scratchpad notes to Google Keep

Tags: google-keep

I would like to move my notes from Scratchpad to the new Google Keep app, but I have not found any way to do that.

How can I do this transfer?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable [Google Drive sync](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375018), all of your scratchpad notes should [automatically transfer](http://support.google.com/chromeos/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=3061306&p=scratchpad_transition). In Chrome *Settings* → *Extensions* → *Scratchpad* → *Options* → **Enable syncing to Google Docs**.

You can also download your notes as plain text files either online or as a .zip file.

note: this worked for me as of May 20, but I could not replicate this on June 8th- the feature may have been disabled

Comment: I did that. In google drive, I have got a folder called Scratchpad which contains all my notes but when I go on google keep there is nothing.

Comment: @Ger Weird- my lists came over... I'll play around with some different note types and see if I can replicate your problem

Comment: @Ger Even I am having the same problem. My notes from google drive are not showing up in Google Keep. Did you had any success?

Comment: @gina I did- but then I went to set the same thing up for my sister and it didn't work- I don't know if the feature was disabled or something...